# Improve SQL Query for Join Table

Tags: sql

I have a table.contact_group, and table.contact
The contact's group is store in "table.contact" in the field "group_id" varchar

example data: ;11;22;33;44;55;

Where the 11,22,33,44,55 is the table.contact_group.group_id

There is a lot of data in the database, i have no way to modify the data. I have to try to change to JOIN query, the performance does not improve.

My last option is, trying hard to modify the database, and create a "connection" table to handle relationship (M:M) between table.contact_group and table.contact

```
SELECT cg.group_id, cg.group_title , COUNT(c.contact_id) AS total 
 FROM nano_contacts_group cg , nano_contacts c 
WHERE cg.organization_id = '1' AND cg.group_active = '1' AND c.group_id LIKE CONCAT('%;',CONCAT( cg.group_id,';%')) 
 GROUP BY cg.group_id
 ORDER BY cg.group_title ASC
```

I hope can have SQL expert share his/her opinion what I suppose to do.

Comment: It's really unclear trying to figure out what your goal is.  Is it that you can't modify your data or that the query performance is too slow?  Either way, please clarify what you're trying to achieve and provide some sample data.  This will make it easier to try to help.

Comment: i'm not too sure what you're really asking for ... the only obvious thing i can see from what you've posted, that could affect performance, is the wildcard at the start of the CONCAT. leading wildcards should be used with caution